# NoMethodError: undefined method `dependency' for Gzip:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running into a weird issue after trying to restart my official Redmine 4.2.3 docker container which is using ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-linux].

I have been running a [plugin](https://github.com/rickbarrette/redmine_qbo/tree/redmine-4) I wrote that uses the quickbooks-ruby gem found [here](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) for years without issues, however now I'm getting the following error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `dependency' for Gzip:Class
/usr/local/bundle/gems/quickbooks-ruby-1.0.19/lib/quickbooks/faraday/middleware/gzip.rb:15:in `<class:Gzip>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/quickbooks-ruby-1.0.19/lib/quickbooks/faraday/middleware/gzip.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/quickbooks-ruby-1.0.19/lib/quickbooks-ruby.rb:16:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/quickbooks-ruby-1.0.19/lib/quickbooks-ruby.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/redmine/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the first 15 lines from [/lib/quickbooks/faraday/middleware/gzip.rb](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/faraday/middleware/gzip.rb)

```
# https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware/blob/master/lib/faraday_middleware/gzip.rb

require 'faraday'

# Middleware to automatically decompress response bodies. If the
# "Accept-Encoding" header wasn't set in the request, this sets it to
# "gzip,deflate" and appropriately handles the compressed response from the
# server. This resembles what Ruby 1.9+ does internally in Net::HTTP#get.
#
# This middleware is NOT necessary when these adapters are used:
# - net_http on Ruby 1.9+
# - net_http_persistent on Ruby 2.0+
# - em_http
class Gzip < Faraday::Middleware
  dependency 'zlib'
```

It seems my issue is with the *dependency* declaration, and I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Please advise & Thank you in advance
-ricky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like quickbooks-ruby is dependent on faraday_middleware:1.2.0,. Nothing specifies this, so faraday:2.x.x is installed instead. To fix this, you can try adding

```
gem 'faraday_middleware', '1.2.0'
```

to your redmine_qbo Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you! You are a lifesaver, I'm not sure what changed since yesterday but this seems to have fixed my issue :)

Comment: Figured out what changed, looks like the oauth2 was updated on 2/18 which broke the quickbooks-ruby integration. Turns out I had to update my Gemfile to use the following

gem 'oauth2', '1.4.7'

https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth2